# Squeeze theorem inequalities

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that the squeeze Theorem holds if $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$.

Does it also hold if $f(x)< g(x)< h(x)$ ? Or maybe a combination of "$\le$" and "$<$"? If not, then can I have a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well $a<b$ implies $a\leq b$. So whatever inequalities ($\leq$ or $<$) you can prove, if $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ have the same limit, then it's fine.